# Automatic dependencies in TeamCity (or other continuous build)?

Tags: dependencies, continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm thinking of implementing a really large continuous build at work (hundreds of Visual Studio solutions, thousands of projects).  It includes .NET, C++, and VB6 code.  We have some solutions building on TeamCity, but dependencies aren't set up right.  Keeping the dependencies in sync between source code and TeamCity (or another tool) sounds totally unrealistic at this scale.  **Does anyone know if there is a tool/plugin to detect solution dependencies automatically in TeamCity? How about with other continuous integration tools?** Even if it only works on .NET projects, that would still be a big help.

I found a small, command line tool ([gittup.org/tup](http://gittup.org/tup)) that says it infers dependencies by monitoring file access. It seems possible to apply this technique to a larger scale build tool, but I don't know if it's been done. Or maybe there is a whole other solution out there.

Comment: Another option is to write a custom tool that extracts dependency info from your project files, then uses TeamCity's REST API to update the build configurations: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin

Answer (score 0):

Detection is tough.

My company's [AnthillPro](http://www.urbancode.com/html/products/anthillpro/) tool is used by teams who have many hundreds of interdependent components and need to manage those builds - and smartly only rebuild the components impacted by a given change.

One approach that I've seen be really successfull is to push the dependency definitions down to developers. Some teams require them to manage a file that lists their inter-solution dependencies - "What other stuff needs to be downloaded and put into a lib/bin directory for your solution to compile". This is similar to what many Java development teams do with Maven. I'd look to distribute the dependency definition across the dev team(s) rather than try to detect.

The role of the build management tool at that point is to parse that file at build time and update its model of the dependency graph behind the scenes. That information can be used both for artifact retrieval, and for triggering related builds.

Comment: I'll take a look at AnthillPro.  I'm trying to avoid having two definitions of the dependencies but I guess we'll see if that's possible. I found a small, command line tool (http://gittup.org/tup/) that says it infers dependencies by monitoring file access.  It seems possible to apply this technique to a larger scale build tool, but I don't know if it's been done.

Comment: Inferring those file level dependencies as part of a giant build is possible. That's how ClearCase's ClearMake works. I think you lose a lot of the benefit of having things broken up into clear solutions in that case though. Maybe your tool works differently though.

Comment: I haven't tried Tup yet, because I don't think it has things like a distributed build, email notifications, hung build detection, a nice web interface, users and permissions, etc.  It was designed to be a small tool.  But it looks like it will handle VisualBuild solutions built via MSBuild, unless I've missed something.  It would be great if someone put a dependency approach similar to Tup's into a large-scale build tool.  It'd be a bit of work in a distributed build, but I think it is possible.

Comment: We've had customers use ec accelerator and Xoreax Incredibuild for this kind of work. You still end up rebuilding the world, but can distribute it. I'm a big fan of knowing your dependency graph, and rebuilding only what's changed at a component level, but distributed make for .Net exists - it just tends to be expensive.